# Как конвертировать .pyw в .exe

Tags: python, windows-10, exe

Пытаюсь разными способами конвертировать **.pyw** файл в **.exe**, пробовал при помощи `pyinstaller -F -w file.pyw`, другие способы из интернета, но всё никак. В папке **dist** просто не появляется **.exe** файл. Операционная система - Windows 10.

Comment: Попробуйте без параметра -w запустить и посмотреть что напишет.

Comment: Нужно смотреть что pyinstaller выводит, от этого уже отталкиваться при решении проблемы.

Comment: Pyinstaller пишет: `Fatal error: PyInstaller does not include a pre-compiled bootloader for your
platform.` Установил bootloader, но ошибка всё та же.

Comment: Судя по этому ответу, проблема может быть из-за антивируса, попробуйте отключить его на время сборки: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67437743/4752653